# In Laravel Scheduler function, everyMinute() does not work

Tags: laravel-5, scheduler

I'm using Laravel 5. In my Schedule method (in kernel.php), i used everyMinute function. Please take a look:

[image]

But its not working. It shows message "Call to undefined method". Please take a look:

[image]

I need to call scheduler every minute via call function. Please help me.

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using ?

Comment: I mentioned it in my question body :) its laravel 5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear to have that method in 5.0.

Use the manual cron expression for every minute.

```
$schedule->call(...)->cron('* * * * * *');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, Laravel is clearly saying you that there is no method defined as `everyMinute` in Schedule. Forget about the [official documentation](https://laravelc.com/docs/5.0), it is not there in the [API Documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/CallbackEvent.html) as well as Laravel 5.0.*.

If you really want that to run every minute, you can upgrade your app to Laravel 5.1.* or greater.

Comment: dont need to upgrade, every minute is just  `cron('* * * * * *')`

Comment: Yep.. I made a mistake.. I must have not read the documentation correctly.. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.. :)

Comment: Nah you read them right :) that method doesn't exist in 5.0, but it is just an alias to `cron('* * * * * *')` in the later versions.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks once again.. :)